# Python variable Name.Error

Tags: python

In python I am writing a program to calculate a grade in a class, taking into account the types of course work, the weight of each, and scores.  This is the code:

```
def get_initial_input():
    try:
        tests = int(input("How many tests are there? "))   #get number of tests
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number")
        get_initial_input()
    class_weight()

def class_weight():
    print("What is the weighted percent of the class?")
    if tests > 0:     #<-- this is where the error is
        try:
            tests_weight = float(input("Tests: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid weight")
            class_weight()

def main():
    get_initial_input()

main()
```

Whenever I run it I get a `builtins.NameError occurred Message: name 'tests' is not defined` error.  It seems like the variable is defined earlier in the program, but it seems that it isn't defined properly for some reason. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `tests` is not known in `class_weight` as it's defined in `get_initial_input`, it's known only in the function's scope.

Comment: Having a function call itself when it gets bad input is not a good design strategy. See if you can re-write your functions to use `while` loops instead. Even better, try to avoid using `input()` in the inner functions of your program, as I discuss in the last paragraph of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25834425/4014959).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_initial_input():
    try:
        tests = int(input("How many tests are there? "))   #get number of tests
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number")
        get_initial_input()
    class_weight(tests)

def class_weight(tests):
    print("What is the weighted percent of the class?")
    if tests > 0:     #<-- this is where the error is
        try:
            tests_weight = float(input("Tests: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid weight")
            class_weight()

def main():
    get_initial_input()

main()
```

Just pass `tests` and it will work.